# error in wicket dataview ,need help to fix it

Tags: java, wicket

Am trying to execute a wicket program to accomplish the below task,
a. a submit button is in place in a form
b. when I click that i have to show the ouput in data view of the same page
My codes are below and need your help to fix the errors and get the ouput

Demoapplication.java

```
package com.demo.application;

import org.apache.wicket.Page;
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication;
import com.demo.pages.*;

public class DemoApplication extends WebApplication {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Page> getHomePage() {
        return DemoHomePage.class;
    }

}
```

DemoHomePage.html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form wicket:id="homePageForm">
        <input type="submit" value="ok">
    </form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th> Id </th>
            <th> Name </th>
        </tr>
        <tr wicket:id="row">
            <td wicket:id="dataRow"> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

DemoHomePage.java

```
package com.demo.pages;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.*;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.*;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.Item;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.RepeatingView;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.data.DataView;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.data.ListDataProvider;

import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.org.objectweb.asm.Label;

public class DemoHomePage extends WebPage {

    public DemoHomePage () {
        Form form=new Form("homePageForm") {

            public void submit(){

                List<DemoBean> list = new ArrayList();
                list.add(new DemoBean("1","ram"));
                list.add(new DemoBean("2","sam"));

                ListDataProvider<DemoBean> listDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<DemoBean>(list);

                DataView<DemoBean> dataView = new DataView<DemoBean>("row",listDataProvider) {

                    protected void populateItem(Item<DemoBean> item) {

                        DemoBean bean=item.getModelObject();
                        RepeatingView repeatingView = new RepeatingView("dataRow");
                        repeatingView.add(new Label(repeatingView.newChildId().bean.getId()));
                        repeatingView.add(new Label(repeatingView.newChildId().bean.getName()));
                        item.add(repeatingView);
                    }
                };

                add(dataView);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

DemoBean.java

```
package com.demo.pages;

public class DemoBean {
    public String id;
    public String name;

    public DemoBean(String id,String name) {
        this.id=id;this.name=name;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id){
        this.id=id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

I am getting the below error.

> Error:  Bound mismatch: The type DemoBean is not a valid substitute
>   for the bounded parameter  of the type
>   ListDataProvider The method add(Component...) in the type
>   MarkupContainer is not applicable for the arguments (Label)

Comment: You're missing some very basic Wicket things here. Check out the hello world example to get your page working [here](http://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/helloworld.html) and an example of some form processing [here](http://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/guestbook.html). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the error message:

1. Your DemoBean class isn't serializable.
2. `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.org.objectweb.asm.Label` is in no way related to a wicket Label

Comment: Thanks friends. I have fixedthe issue by making it serializable and include the label class.

Comment: Run time error is below:
WicketMessage: Unable to find component with id 'row' in [Page class = com.demo.pages.DemoHomePage, id = 4, version = 0]. This means that you declared wicket:id=row in your markup, but that you either did not add the component to your page at all, or that the hierarchy does not match.
[markup = file:/home/kumar/Documents/javaapplications/Eclipse_Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/demo/WEB-INF/classes/com/demo/pages/DemoHomePage.html

Comment: am using the row id inside submit method , how we could resolve the issue,please help